Telegram bot не работают кнопки
Пишу бота чтобы с обратной связью. Столкнулся с проблемой, что не работает функционал кнопок в функции "nes"
import telebot
from telebot import types
from time import sleep


bot = telebot.TeleBot("My token")

@bot.message_handler(commands=["start"])
def start(message):
    markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
    btn1 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Ассортимент магазина", callback_data= "assort")
    btn2 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Заказ товаров", callback_data= "zakaz")
    btn3 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Связь с менеджером", callback_data= "svaz")
    markup.row(btn1)
    markup.row(btn2, btn3)
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f"Привет, {message.from_user.first_name}, что вас интересует?", reply_markup= markup)



@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: True)
def ans(callback):#Кнопки
    if callback.data == "assort":
        bot.send_message(callback.message.chat.id, "Вот такой ассортимент")
    elif callback.data == "zakaz":
        bot.send_message(callback.message.chat.id, "Заказывайте у нас товар")
    elif callback.data == "svaz":
        msg = bot.send_message(callback.message.chat.id, "Напишите свое сообщение")
        bot.register_next_step_handler(msg, nes)

def nes(message):
    name = message.text
    markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
    btn1 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Ответить на вопрос", callback_data="otve")
    btn2 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Внести в ЧС", callback_data="csa")
    markup.add(btn1, btn2)
    bot.send_message("ID чата",f"Новое сообщение от пользователя:\n-{name}\n ID пользователя: {message.chat.id}", reply_markup= markup)

@bot.callback_query_handler(func = lambda callback: True)
def callback_message(callback):
    if callback.data == "otve":
        bot.send_message("ID чата", "Напишите сообщение")
    elif callback.data == "csa":
        bot.send_message("ID чата", "напишите сообщение")

bot.polling(none_stop= True)


Попробуй использовать вместо message.text message.chat.id, не уверен, но мб поможет, у тебя описано message.text, а ты используешь message.chat.id

Здравствуйте, а  где именно?

После блока def nes
